# Push Notification condition

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

Good day,

I am using Parse Push Notification, and below are my difficulties:
In brief, I would like to "merge" these two conditions:

```
 query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
  pushQuery.whereEqualTo("the gender column of the ParseQuery", the user gender of the ParseQuery column);
```

In other words, I would like to send out a message to the user that falls within that gender. The gender column along with the genders are found in the parse query called "User".

Update: 
userLookingGender is the following:

```
 String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
            "Looking_Gender");
```

If you need any clarification let me know.

**Update 2:**
I use one condition, gender, to make easier to understand. Now Imagine if I had multiple condition, and is trying to send a push message only the recipient who fulfill all of the below criteria, and where upon button click it would take them to particular activity page.

```
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                            .getObjectId());
                    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
                    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
                    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
                    query.setLimit(1) ;

                    ParseGeoPoint point = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseGeoPoint("location");
                    query.whereWithinKilometers("location", point, mMax_Distance.doubleValue());

                    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
                    query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("UserAge", minimumAge);
                    query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("UserAge", maximumAge);
```

**Update 3:**

Android Code

```
                ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendPushToNearbyAndMatching", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<String>() {
                  public void done(String result, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                      // success
                    }
                  }
                });
```

**Parse Cloud JavaScript code (found in cloud/main.js)**
The owner column in this case is users

```
 // Use Parse.Cloud.define to define as many cloud functions as you want.
    // For example:
    Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
      response.success("Hello world!");
    });

Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushToNearbyAndMatching", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    // the authenticated user on the device calling this function
    var user = request.user; 

    // the complex query matching users
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", user.id);
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.equalTo("Gender", user.get("Gender"));
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.equalTo("Looking_Gender", user.get("Looking_Gender"));
    query.equalTo("ActivityName", user.get("ActivityName"));

    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("UserAge", user.get("Minimum_Age"));
   query.lessThanOrEqualTo("UserAge", user.get("Maximum_Age"));
    query.limit(1);


    query.each(function(user) {
        // sendPushNotification is added in next code section
        return sendPushNotification(user);
    }).then(function() {
        response.success("success!");
    }, function(err) {
        response.error(err);
    });

});


 var sendPushNotification = function(user) {

     var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
     query.equalTo('users', user);

     return Parse.Push.send({
         where : query, // send to installations matching query
         expiration_interval : 600, // optional - expires after 10 minutes
         data : {
             alert: "App says hello!",
         }
     })
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it would be much easier if you save "Gender" and "Looking_Gender" of the user to the `Installation` object. Then you can target the installations for the push using a single query. Or perhaps I misunderstood, must admit the question is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: I see where your getting at, but I do not want to create unnecessary request. In the sense that if the gender of a user is already stored in parse under the "User" table, than wouldn't be better to just grab the information from there as oppose to create a new column called Gender through installation. The reason why it was store there is because I am not just using Push notification, in many activities I make reference to parsequery.

Comment: To clarify, is both values already saved on the User objects, or?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  The Gender column and the genders under that column are already saved in the User objects. Which is why I was trying to do the following pushQuery.whereEqualTo("the gender column from User, the current user gender);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I have a bit more insight I think I'm ready with an answer:

I do Push from Cloud Code, and there the query matches against Installation objects, which is why having the values there as well would be useful.

It looks like you are sending directly from the app, so I would suggest creating a channel for each gender: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-channels/Android

Then you just need to:

```
String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
        "Looking_Gender");
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setChannel(userLookingGender);
push.setMessage("Your message");
push.sendInBackground();
```

**Update:**

Ok. the multiple queries indeed make matters more complicated.

I think you would have to move on to Cloud Code to perform such an advanced query push (which is by the way recommended for security reasons).

Cloud Code guide: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

Embrasing the fact that users can have multiple devices, you need to be able to fetch all the installations associated with a user. To do this I would suggest saving a pointer to User on each installation. You can do this as part of the first login of your app.

Assuming you have a, say, `owner` column in your installation pointing to the respective User owning the device, then you can do something like this in Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushToNearbyAndMatching", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    // the authenticated user on the device calling this function
    var user = request.user; 

    // the complex query matching users
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", user.id);
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.equalTo("Gender", user.get("Gender"));
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.equalTo("Looking_Gender", user.get("Looking_Gender"));
    query.limit(1);

    ... etc

    // execute the query
    // i am using each just to show an convenient way to iterate the results
    // instead of setting limit(1) consider executing the query using first() instead 
    // android SDK has a getFirstInBackground() as well

    query.each(function(user) {
        // sendPushNotification is added in next code section
        return sendPushNotification(user);
    }).then(function() {
        response.success("success!");
    }, function(err) {
        response.error(err);
    });

});
```

About querying User in javascript: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-querying

How to call this Cloud function from Android: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#cloudfunctions

Now it is time to send out the notifications to the devices owned by the user:

```
 var sendPushNotification = function(user) {

     var promise = new Parse.Promise();

     var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
     query.equalTo('owner', user);

     query.count().then(function(count) {
         console.log("sending push to " + count + " devices");
         Parse.Push.send({
             where : query, // send to installations matching query
             expiration_interval : 600, // optional - expires after 10 minutes
             data : {
                alert: "App says hello!",
             }
        }).then(function() {
            // success
            console.log("push success");
            promise.resolve();
        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            promise.reject(error);
        });
    });

    return promise;
}
```

For more advanced pushes (if you for instance want to receive a broadcast to handle some data) see: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/JavaScript

Also, if you decide to fiddle with Cloud Code and thereby javascript, I would highly recommend having a look at how promises work. This makes your life so much easier when handling asynchronous calls, for instance when issuing queries: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises

This is all a lot of information and probably a lot to take in all at once if it is new to you, but I think it will be all worth it, I know it was for me.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a response. I have included an update under the update2 section of my initial post.

Comment: No problem :) I know how I have struggled with similar challenges. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I admitetly admit that it will take a bit for me to grasbp all of these information, but i trust it would be worth it. Would you by chance know how would translate the javascript code into android, as it does seem to read it at its current form. Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by translating the javascript into android? In case it is because you are unfamiliar with Cloud Code: the javascript is run directly on the parse.com servers.

Comment: I have looked into parse cloud more, and have applied your suggestions. I am not sure if I properly applied because the push notification does not seem to be react. I have includes the codes under the update 3 section of my initial post.

Comment: It is partially untested code, so may need some correction. You can see if the logs has any error output and add `console.log('text')` statements to see what happens. Additionally, if either of the two queries does not find any results, for whatever reason, no push notification is sent. So a additional debug step could be to remove `where : query` to send the notification to everyone, just to make sure that the code reaches that point at least.

Comment: Updated `sendPushNotification` to log (at the cost of an extra query) the number of devices that gets notfications.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a feeling that the connection between the cloud and the code may not even been established because after removing all those conditions, I see no push even through parse. From my understanding the files were deploy properly as it consistently says "uploading source files" and finished uploading files.

Comment: You can see if the code is uploaded correctly to your project at https://parse.com/apps/<nameofyourproject>/cloud_code/script also here you find a "logs" option in the left side.

Comment: thank you. My last small question is how do i directly determine the activity that the user is going to be landed once they click on the push. By default it goes to a specific activity, but I could have multiple push that could take user to a different activity. Wouldn't it be possible to also display the push in-app by for instance through a popup

Comment: All of that is indeed possible with advance pushes. You can define which broadcast to trigger once the push reaches your app in the ´action´ part of the ´data´ when you send a push (think it was described in one of the links I added). Once the push triggers a BroadcastReceiver you can do whatever you wish to do: Create your own notification pointing to a specific Activity, show a dialog, or something completely different. I am for example updating data in the Local Datastore in the background using push notifications.